# Conflicting versions of composer installed package causing issues

Tags: macos, composer-php, codeception

I'm running mac OS X and trying to use codeception through the terminal for a laravel project I'm working on, but I'm having some issues related to the version. The `codecept` command through terminal is referencing an older version and I cannot figure out how to change the reference to the newer one.

When I type in `codecept -v` in terminal it shows 2.1.6. However, when I type in `./vendor/bin/codecept` it shows 2.4.1. So, every time I need to use codeception I now have to type `./vendor/bin/codecept some_command`, which is quite aggravating.

How can I change it so that I don't have to type out `./vendor/bin/codecept` every single time I need to run a codeception command and can instead just use `codecept`, which the older version is currently referencing? I tried using `export PATH=$PATH:./vendor/bin/codecept` but that didn't do anything.

Comment: What shows `whereis codecept`?

Comment: @rob006 nothing appears when I run that.

Answer (score 1):

Try run:

```
export PATH=./vendor/bin:$PATH
```

It will prefer binaries from local composer installation.

You may want to add it to your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` file, then you will not need to run this command in every session.

---

If your global Codeception installation is installed by Composer, you should be able to update it by:

```
composer global require codeception/codeception
```

But I would not recommend to use global installation - required Codeception version may vary for different projects, so using version installed locally should give you less trouble and more predictable results.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me is:

1. Install Composer
   Navigate to your desired location and copy this set of commands in your terminal:

> php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer',
>   'composer-setup.php');"
>
> php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') ===
>   '669656bab3166a7aff8a7506b8cb2d1c292f042046c5a994c43155c0be6190fa0355160742ab2e1c88d40d5be660b410')
>   { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt';
>   unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
>
> php composer-setup.php
>
> php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

2. Install latest Codeception via Composer:
   In terminal type:

> composer require codeception/codeception --dev